# Is $F$ surjective if $\det (DF(x,y))\neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

given $F(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$. Can I say that $F$ is surjective since $\det(DF(x,y))\neq 0$ iff $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ and $F(0,0)=(0,0)$?

Comment: You can only deduce *local* surjectivity/injectivity near a point in the image (by the Inverse Function Theorem). However, this particular function you can analyze directly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. By the same argument, if $G(x,y)=(e^x,e^y)$, then $G$ would be surjective. But, in fact, $G(\mathbb R^2)=(0,\infty)^2\neq\mathbb R^2$.